# Difference between value and reference in a Java exercise?

Tags: java, class

I am learning Java from [Udemy, complete java masterclass](https://www.udemy.com/java-the-complete-java-developer-course/). For challenge "Abstract class challenge" narrator states says I should create 2 references and 1 value in an abstract class.

In the solution this is the result:

```
public abstract class ListItem {
    // references
    protected ListItem rightLink = null;
    protected ListItem leftLink = null;

    // value
    protected Object object;
}
```

What makes references a reference and not a value?

They both start with protected, then we have type, then we have variable name. The only difference is that reference has assigned value of null.

But if were to make for example:

```
private int myNumber = 10;
```

Above is not called a reference, it is called a variable myNumber of type int with value 10.

Comment: I changed code a little bit to better illustrate my question.

Comment: you should switch to another study material IMHO. Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @Andremoniy That is not a duplicate. This question is not about pass-by-reference/pass-by-value, it is about what the linked course material means with reference/value in a specific context.

Comment: For me the contents of this question are immaterial, because it is all quite a nonsense (what the connection between reference and field access modifiers??). I am looking at the essence which is given in the topic of the question, and it is certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @Andremoniy The course material does not try to teach anything about how reverences/values are passed in method calls though, they just used the terms "reference" and "value" to describe a data structure. I don't see how the linked question helps to complete the challenge.

Comment: @Kapep first of all S.O. is not a place for completing the challenges.

Comment: @Andremoniy meh, I was about to edit that to "understand the challenge", which is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Again, not a proper place. I personally don't see how this question (with the given contents) might be worth for anybody else OP. We can not discuss here each incompetent tutorials

Answer (score 12):

It is not a value in the context of the *Java language*.
In the context of the Java language, all three fields are references.

I see it as a value in the context of a *linked list*.
In context of a linked list, an object of type `Object` is going to be an actual value that is stored in the list. And `ListItem` is a reference to another list item because that is how linked lists are connected.

Seems like the course material does not make it as clear as it should.

Comment: This is the right answer, at least for it being a context issue :)

Answer (score 3):

Word "value" and "reference" have very specific meaning in the context of programming languages, including Java.

However, this distinction does not apply here, because both links and the object are implemented using references. Authors are using these words in a more abstract sense of implementing data structures.

Generally, a data structure has storage for "payload" data, and optionally for data needed to support the inner workings of the data structure itself:

- An array has space only for payload data,
- A linked list has additional space for a link to the next node,
- A tree has additional space for links to parent and child nodes,
- A hash table has additional space for hash buckets

and so on. When authors say "value" they mean a variable for storing the "payload" data; when they say "reference" they mean variables for storing auxiliary information enabling the inner working of your data structure. In this case, it looks like they want you to build a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).

Answer (score 2):

I think this tutorial show you how to create LinkedList. So ListItem must keep references on next and previous Item, so your references is:

```
protected ListItem rightLink = null;
protected ListItem leftLink = null;
```

And for addition each Item can keep some values, so your value is:

```
protected Object object;
```

It can be any other class variable, but tutorial creaters want Object.

Answer (score -1):

**Passing by Value vs. by Reference Visual Explanation**

[image: Visual Explanation]

I think you visit the link [Passing by Value vs. by Reference](https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical/) ,you can find find the solution